# Default Replacing Linked Objects Source - Excel/PPT VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I've been using this code for a while now with some bugs every now and then:

```
 Sub UpdateSheet()    Dim sld As Slide
        Dim sh As Shape
        Dim strNms As String
        Dim intI As Integer
        Dim strNewPath
        Dim ExcelFile
        Dim exl As Object
        Set exl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

         'Open a dialog box to promt for the new source file.
        ExcelFile = exl.Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select Excel File")
        For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
            For Each sh In sld.Shapes
                If sh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
                    With sh.LinkFormat
                        strNms = .SourceFullName
                        intI = InStr(1, strNms, "!")
                        strNewPath = ExcelFile & Mid(strNms, intI, Len(strNms) - intI + 1)
                        .SourceFullName = strNewPath
                    End With
                End If
            Next sh
        Next sld
        ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
    End Sub
```

The problem is, linked objects also contain a section within brackets, for example: [MyDocument.xlsm]Chart 1.

The code above, changes the string all up until !, but does not change the section within brackets also.

Any recommendations on how to loop for that section or any better code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give an example of *initial* string input and desired *final* output?

Comment: Initial string input would be "c:/mydocuments/folder/Source1.xlsm!Sheet1[Source1.xlsm]Chart1"
New output would be:
"c:/mydocuments/folder/Source2.xlsm!Sheet1[Source2.xlsm]Chart1"
Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Can't you just `Replace` "Source1" with "Source2"?

Comment: Not within the linked objects though, also occasionally the file path may change.

Comment: I don't think you understand my suggestion. Use the `Replace` VBA function.

Answer (score 1):

> Initial string input would be "c:/mydocuments/folder/Source1.xlsm!Sheet1[Source1.xlsm]Chart1" New output would be: "c:/mydocuments/folder/Source2.xlsm!Sheet1[Source2.xlsm]Chart1"

I think you should be able to just use the `Replace` function:

[image]

Here is the example code:

```
Dim initialName as String
Dim newName as String
Dim strReplace as String
Dim strReplacement as String

initialName =  "c:/mydocuments/folder/Source1.xlsm!Sheet1[Source1.xlsm]Chart1"
strReplace = "Source1"
strReplacement = "Source2"
newName = Replace(initialName, strReplace, strReplacement)

MsgBox newName
```

In your case, it is not entirely clear what you intend to do. But this should be your process:

1. Determine the original string (I think this is `strNms` in your code.
2. Determine *what part of that string* is going to be replaced (`strReplace`). Is it *always* "Source1" or is it "Source" & *n* where *n* might be any integer value?  Will that integer always be one digit in length or could it be longer? These make a difference in how you resolve the problem.
3. Determine *what the replacement will be* (`strReplacement`). Is it *always* "Add one to the previous name?" Or might it be something else?
4. once you determine these, then you simply do:

   `.SourceFullName = Replace(strNms, strReplace, strReplacement)`

Comment: Gotcha, I see what you're doing. However, it's only changing the file name, not the full path based on a selection (to make this more dynamic). I might be able to find a way to build this into the existing code, but I'm not 100% positive.

Comment: What? You indicated an example input, and desired output. This function does **exactly** what you asked for: converts the input to the output.  If this is not correct, please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: What don't you understand how to do?

Comment: I guess, I'm asking in the context of the rest of the code. To loop for each linked object, and change the source of that linked object based on the new linked file. The issue I'm running into is that the original linked files appear as "c:/mydocuments/Sheet1.xlsm!Sheet1[Source1.xlsm]Chart1" but when replaced using the code above, get repalced to only "c:/mydocuments/Sheet2.xlsm" and doesn't retain the rest of the source, which often leads to bugs in the reference causing broken charts. Hope that explains more.

Comment: Then you have not done something correctly. Can you kindly revise your original question to include the code you are currently attempting to use? I will gladly look it over and find your error :)

Comment: The original question contains the code that I'm currently using.

Comment: The question contains your original code. Here I expect you to *try* to implement the method described in my answer. If you aren't able to implement it successfully, revise the Q to include your attempt.  I am not writing your code for you, I'm trying to help. If you'd like further assistance, please show some effort.

Comment: Fair enough! I'll take a stab at it. Thanks for your help and sorry about the confusion!

Comment: I made a small revision to describe the *process* for you. While it would be plenty easy for me to simply write your code, I would rather help you learn how to fix it on your own :)